# Mixed error pages in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2 x64, Classic mode. In ASP.NET 3.5 apps, IIS is *concatenating* the default error pages (e.g. `inetpub\custerr\en-US\500.htm`) with my own custom error pages (as defined in web.config, section `customErrors`). It first displays the default one, then my custom page, in the same response.

Obviously, I only want my own custom error pages to show up. How do I prevent IIS from using the default pages? How is it even *possible* that the two pages are mixed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: tried, didn't work :(