# Overwriting entire IIS configuration

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

Somehow I managed to fix [Mixed error pages in IIS 7.5](https://serverfault.com/questions/321156/mixed-error-pages-in-iis-7-5) on my Windows 7 x64 dev box, which is also IIS 7.5. Or I should rather say "it works" instead of "I fixed it", since I don't really know what was wrong in the first place.

I copied my applicationHost.config and web.config to the production server, but it doesn't work there.

What other config file am I missing? How can I overwrite the **entire** IIS configuration on the production server with my own? Is there a complete list of files that includes the whole configuration?

Comment: I'm confused.  First you say it "works", then a sentence later you say it doesn't work.  Why not just use the Windows component installer to remove IIS and reinstall it?  What error messages are you getting specifically?

Comment: @GregD : edited to make it more clear that it works on my dev box but not on the production box.

Comment: @GregD : reinstalling IIS is similar to "programming by coincidence". I'd rather understand what I'm doing and why, so I don't have to reinstall everything every time I have a problem.

Comment: @GregD : I described in the linked question what's wrong and what's the server response and how it differs from the expected response. What I'm asking here is a different question: how can I overwrite the entire IIS configuration on the production server with the one on my dev box?

Comment: You still didn't answer my question.  What error message are you getting?  Telling us "it doesn't work there" isn't really telling us anything.  This could literally be HUNDREDS of things wrong and HUNDREDS of different ways of fixing it..It could be you don't have a correct versino of .NET installed...it could be a setting in IIS that needs to be turned off/on, it could be the sun isn't aligned properly.  I think you'll get more help if you include more specifics as opposed to just saying "it doesn't work."

Comment: @GregD : again I refer you to the linked question, where I explain: "It first displays the default one, then my custom page, in the same response."

Comment: @GregD : again I must point to you that this is a different question, there is no error involved here. I'm just asking "how can I overwrite the entire IIS configuration on the production server with the one on my dev box?"

Comment: @GregD: No, I want to have a complete list of files so I can compare them with my production server, so I can understand what's wrong. Please keep your sarcasm at home, I have not disrespected you. If you're not interested in my question then don't answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I solved this type of problems dropping and recreating ASP.NET application (if an ASP.NET app).

For the errors problem, i solved with:

```
  <system.webServer>    
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />  
  </system.webServer>
```

in application web.config; but this can be made also on entire IIS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! However this is an answer for my other question, not for this one.